# Add Folder Name on Desktop

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments

I cannot get the title of a folder on my desktop to display the name.  Is there a way to get this working in 14.04?

This (from a Mac) is what I am trying to get to:

[image]

This is what my Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop looks like, with two folders.  Those folders do not have labels, so I don't know which is which.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more what do you want?

Comment: Are you unable to create folder on desktop ?

Comment: Can't you add screenshot of ubuntu or make it more clear

Comment: Added a screenshot of my Ubuntu Desktop, showing two folders with no labels, so I don't know which folder is which.

Comment: Jacob, they do have names.  I can view the names in Nautilus, and via a bash terminal.  I just don't see the folder names on the Desktop.  When you create a folder on your Desktop, is it labeled?

Comment: Ok, so all you people who have commented, and to the gentleman who downvoted the question - have you tried creating a folder under "Desktop", and does the folder icon show on the Desktop WITH a label?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are my desktop icons really small and without text?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/394610/why-are-my-desktop-icons-really-small-and-without-text) - it looks quite similar. Also http://askubuntu.com/questions/23570/how-can-i-hide-the-text-under-the-desktop-icons may help

Comment: I am using the default theme - Ambience.  I can't think of anything custom that I added that would affect this behavior. I don't have any bizarre fonts, either. So, you're saying that you see the folder icons with labels?

Comment: Tim, you nailed it.  It was the question 394610, the first link you cited.  Thanks very much.  Solved.   Wish I could award you points.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is it that you want. Here are steps on how to create or rename a folder on your desktop in Ubuntu very plainly explained:

1) Right click on your desktop
2) Click "new folder"
3) Name the folder

If you want to rename an existing folder, right click on the folder and click "rename".

Comment: I got that, but when I create a folder on my desktop, there is a folder icon, but no label.  I want the folder name as part of the label.  Just having a bunch of unlabeled folder icons on my Desktop, not knowing which is which, is not very useful.